# Flutter: How can I avoid recreating the model for parts of the application?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

My app uses a set of `Card()`s inside a `PageView()`, each card has multiple text lines.
The user gives input for each line (e.g. modifying the text etc.).
I want to keep this input for a while.

This is how my code looks at the moment, abstractly speaking:

```
class MyCard extends StatefulWidget {

  final List<Widget> _myLines = [];

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyCardState();
}

class MyCardState extends State<MyCard> {

  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    ...

    widget._myLines.add(ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (context) => MyLineModel(context, lineText),
              child: RecipeLine())

    ...
  }
}
```

This doesn't work well: 
As soon as I swipe left / right through the `PageView` onto other cards and then swipe back, the `Card` is being built again. This also leads to a rebuild of `MyLineModel`, which in turn erases all the user's input.

How can I avoid the rebuild of `MyLineModel` and keep the user's input?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in 2 ways:

1. Create the model outside the widget and pass the model for the widget, as a variable to a constructor for example, or using `Provider` or any other technique of Dependency Injection.
2. Using any of the `KeepAlive` APIs, such as the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` as:

```dart
class MyCardState extends State<MyCard> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

...

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: About the first approach: I could, for example, build an app-wide ("global") registry with a `Map<SomeKey, MyLineModel>`, and use `Provider` and a map lookup to get it. But that doesn't really sound elegant, does it...?

I tried the second approach, it does make the `MyCard`s rebuild less often. Still, sometimes a rebuild is triggered, and I really want to avoid that, so not really a good solution for me...
(Note that I don't mind a rebuild of the `State<MyCard>`, I just don't want the `MyLineModel` to be recreated)

Comment: It shouldn't be recreated at all using keep alive, so another part or your application is triggering the rebuild. For the Map you proposed, I don't see why you need it, if you need to provide several things, use a `MultiProvider`. That being said, I don't recommend that you create all the models at once if you don't need them, try to create them as closer as you will use them, otherwise you will bloat your code unnecessarily.

Answer (score -1):

As the [official documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProvider-class.html) states, we can simply use the `ChangeNotifierProvider.value()` constructor...

In the original code:

```
class MyCardState extends State<MyCard> {

  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    ...

    widget._myLines.add(ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: MyLineModel(context, lineText),
              child: RecipeLine())

    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. The `value` constructor should be used if you already have the value from outside. In your case you are creating the value in place, so it will be recreated each time your card state is rebuild. You complained the state is rebuilt all the time, so the solution is to bring it outside or use a keep alive, which is exactly my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but my app currently works with the `.value()` constructor, and previously didn't work with your solution.